# Find the rotation angles of a plane, given ABCD

Tags: c++, math, 3d, plane

Apologies in advance for my lack of knowledge in this field. I have a c++ function that returns a Plane, as four floats, like so:

`float plane[4]; // will contain the computed plane equation result`

If these floats are `A,B,C,D`, how can I get the actual angles of the plane (in degrees) as X,Y,Z?

For example, the function with test data returns:

`1, 0, 0, -341.336`

How should I be computing angles from this data?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Coefficients A,B,C define normal vector. You can easily find angles of normal with axes through arrcosine function. Example for OX axis:

```
 Len = Length(N) = Sqrt(A^2+B^2+C^2)
 Angle(N, OX) = ArcCos(DotProduct(N, OX) / Len) =
                ArcCos(DotProduct(N, OX)) / Len) =
                ArcCos(DotProduct((A,B,C), (1,0,0))) / Len) =
                ArcCos((A * 1 + B * 0 + C * 0) / Len) =
                ArcCos(A / Len)
 for your example
  Angle(N, OX) = ArcCos(1/1) = 0  (normal coincides with OX ort)
  Angle(N, OY) = ArcCos(0/1) = Pi/2
  Angle(N, OZ) = ArcCos(0/1) = Pi/2
```

Comment: Thanks!  So abc are a normal vector,  is d the rotation amount?

Comment: No, d has no relation to rotation. It might be considered as distance from plane to coordinate origin (if a,b,c are normalized)

Comment: ok, I think I understand. So what i need is to take a normal vector (A,B,C) and convert it to angles. I will try to find an example in c++. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Yes. Note that for normalized (unit) normal vector A,B,C are "direction cosines"

Comment: Sorry, I am stuck. in the above code, `Angle(N, OY) = ArcCos(0/1) = Pi/2` Why the two `=`? How can i do this in c++?

Comment: It is not code, it is formula with result demonstration.